# For loop in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I have set of statements

```
sol[ξ_] := NDSolve[{D[f[η], {η, 3}] + f[η] f''[η] + β (1 - (f'[η])^2) == 0, 
   f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == ξ}, {f[η]}, {η, 0, 5}]

β = 0;

DFEnd[ξ_?NumericQ] := D[f[η] /. sol[ξ], {η, 1}] /. η -> 5

SOL1 = FindRoot[DFEnd[ξ] == 1, {ξ, 0.5}]

plt1 = Plot[Evaluate[D[f[η] /. sol[ξ /. SOL1], {η, 1}]], {η, 0, 5},
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, PlotRange -> All];
```

This is working fine, but what I want is to have a For loop in which my Beta starts from lets say 0 and i increase it to 0.25 everytime till 1 and block of code is executed.
Then I can use Show[plt[1],plt[2],plt[3]...] command to add up every graph.
is this can be done?

Comment: You code is broken, uses constructs that make no sense (e.g. greeks). Please post a minimal working example. Once you have that, something like `Table` will likely serve your purpose.

Comment: Seems like backslashes were eaten up somewhere...

Comment: I fixed your code using Halirutan's [awesome browser script](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1043/862). Generally it is simpler just to avoid using Greek letters in code you post here.

Answer (score 4):

This should do what you're asking:

```
sol[ξ_] := 
 NDSolve[{D[f[η], {η, 3}] + 
     f[η] f''[η] + β (1 - (f'[η])^2) == 0, 
   f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == ξ}, {f[η]}, {η, 0, 
   5}]

β = 0;

DFEnd[ξ_?NumericQ] := 
  D[f[η] /. sol[ξ], {η, 1}] /. η -> 5;

Table[SOL1 = FindRoot[DFEnd[ξ] == 1, {ξ, 0.5}];
  Plot[Evaluate[
    D[f[η] /. sol[ξ /. SOL1], {η, 1}]], {η, 0, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, PlotRange -> All], {β, 0, 1, .25}];

Show @@ %
```

[image]

And off I am to get the script Simon ref'd above...

Comment: @rasher- Thank you very much for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

Small changes:

```
DFEnd[ξ_?NumericQ] := D[f[η] /. sol[ξ], {η, 1}] /. η -> 5

sol1[β_] := FindRoot[DFEnd[ξ] == 1, {ξ, 0.5}]
```

Visualizing:

```
Plot[
  Evaluate[
    Flatten[Table[D[f[η] /. sol[ξ /. sol1[β]], {η, 1}], {β, 0, 1, 0.25}]] /. η -> x], 
  {x, 0, 5}, 
  PlotLegends -> Range[0, 1, 0.25]]
```

[image]

Comment: @m_goldberg- Thanks alot for helping me out

Comment: What if I try to plot this with manipulate option. 
The reason why I want to use Manipulate is my

β and f[0] both are varying. I could plot with varying     both as done for β only. But then it becomes impossible to read anything from the plots

    `Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[
   Flatten[Table[
      D[f[\[Eta]] /. sol[\[Xi] /. sol11[k]], {\[Eta], 1}], {k, 0, 0.6,
        0.2}]] /. \[Eta] -> x], {x, 0, 5}, 
  PlotLegends -> Range[0, 0.6, 0.2], Filling -> True], {\[Beta], 0, 
  2}]`.

But β is assigned a value in the starting only. So, is there any way?

Comment: @user11948 I certainly value m_goldberg insight, however, the original answer was mine (for what that's worht). See separate  answer to deal with your most recent comment.

Answer (score 2):

I am posting a separate answer to answer the question in the comment.

I have rewritten the OP code:

```
sol[\[Xi]_, \[Beta]_] := 
 NDSolve[{D[f[\[Eta]], {\[Eta], 3}] + 
     f[\[Eta]] f''[\[Eta]] + \[Beta] (1 - (f'[\[Eta]])^2) == 0, 
   f[0] == 0, f'[0] == 0, f''[0] == \[Xi]}, {f[\[Eta]]}, {\[Eta], 0, 
   5}]
de[\[Xi]_?NumericQ, b_] := 
 D[f[\[Eta]] /. sol[\[Xi], b], {\[Eta], 1}] /. \[Eta] -> 5
xi[b_] := x /. FindRoot[de[x, b], {x, 0.5}]
fun[b_] := D[First[f[\[Eta]] /. sol[xi[b], b]], {\[Eta], 1}];
```

Using `Manipulate` (note: this system is extremely sensitive to parameters and I have used discrete[`SetterBar`] values of parameter rather than continuous. It provides the qualitative insight into behaviour. I have not looked at analytical aspects):

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Evaluate[fun[b] /. \[Eta] -> x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotLegends -> b, 
  PlotRange -> {-3, 1}], {b, Range[0.1, 1, 0.1], 
  ControlType -> SetterBar}]
```

[image]

Comment: I am using the same code with some modifications to calculate for temperature and velocity profile for flow over a wedge where m is related to my wedge angle. 
The code is working for postive values of m but having some issues with negative values.